# Raise an event from C++/CLI to C#

Tags: c#, c++-cli

I am trying to raise an event from a CLI/C++ class back to C#.

My code is shown below.

Calling **WriteLog** function should fire the event. But when runtime the event is not firing. Also no error is visible

----C++/CLI-----

'''

```
public ref class CLoggerCLI
{
public:
    CLoggerCLI();
    ~CLoggerCLI();
    delegate void NotificationDelegate(System::String^ message);
    event NotificationDelegate^ NotificationEvent;
    void WriteLog(string message);
    static CLoggerCLI^ GetSingleInstnace();

private:
    static CLoggerCLI^ singleInstance;
    static Object^ m_lock = gcnew Object();

};

void CLoggerCLI::WriteLog(string message)
{
    System::String^ msg = gcnew System::String(message.c_str());
    NotificationEvent(msg);
}
```

'''

----C#----

'''

```
  public class TestClass
    {
        #region Private Fields

        private CLoggerCLI loggerCLI = new CLoggerCLI();

        #endregion


        #region Public Method
        public TestClass()
        {
            this.loggerCLI.NotificationEvent += LoggerCLI_NotificationEvent;
        }

        private void LoggerCLI_NotificationEvent(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"*****{message}****");
        }
}
```

'''

Comment: Question unclear. The whole point of the CLI is, that the source language does not mater. You can use a DLL compiled from C++/CLI the same way as VB/CLI, C# and F#.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the problem. The issue was with instance creation. I was actually implementing CLI as a singleton class and I was creating another object in C# code. Use the same instance in C# will sove the above problem

----C++/CLI-----

'''

```
public ref class CLoggerCLI
{
public:

    delegate void NotificationDelegate(System::String^ message);
    event NotificationDelegate^ NotificationEvent;
    void WriteLog(string message);
    static CLoggerCLI^ GetSingleInstnace();

private:
    static CLoggerCLI^ singleInstance;
    static Object^ m_lock = gcnew Object();
    CLoggerCLI();
    ~CLoggerCLI();

};

void CLoggerCLI::WriteLog(string message)
{
    System::String^ msg = gcnew System::String(message.c_str());
    NotificationEvent(msg);
}
```

'''

----C#----

'''

```
  public class TestClass
    {



        #region Public Method
        public TestClass()
        {
            CLoggerCLI.GetSingleInstnace().NotificationEvent += LoggerCLI_NotificationEvent;
        }

        private void LoggerCLI_NotificationEvent(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"*****{message}****");
        }
}
```

'''